# Move filter block RWD in theme

Tags: magento-1.9, css, layered-navigation, magento-community

I have been working on my own custom theme based from the default RWD theme in 1.9.2. However, the filter block is weirdly moving top of page and outside the body. (see fig1)

**FIGURE 1**

[image]

However, this only occurs on the main products page, not on any sub category pages. (see figure 2)

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I haven't touched the default code for filters from rwd theme.

Edit: Still trying to figure this out and analysing the code:

the div "col-left sidebar col-left-first" has broken outside the body in the culpable category, whereas in all other categories it resides in col-wrapper div

Comment: If it's in live share that url

Comment: @Kothari sorry pal not yet live

Comment: you have extra </div> some where in your code

Comment: @AhmedElAwadi I have not editied any of the files for the filter, and other category pages are fine ?

Comment: did you edit 2columns-left.phtml or catalog.xml

Comment: Nope haven't touched 2columns-left.phtml nor catalog.xml. Very strange how its just that one category. Others are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I moved all the subcategories into a new parent category and deleted the old one. This has done the trick